# jQuery Mobile scaling icon in span

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to put a standard jQuery Mobile icon inline with a span element, and scale the icon:

```
<span ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-refresh style="position:relative;background-size:75%;"/>
```

The icon is placed perfectly, however the background-size has no effect. A !important does not help.

Answer (score 2):

The icon image is actually applied to the :after pseudoelement.  So your background CSS needs to applied there:

```
<span class="ui-icon-refresh ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></span>

.inlineIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
.inlineIcon:after {
    background-size: 75% !important;
}
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rumxqunb/1/)**

Comment: It shrinks the icon, however the contrast disc behind the icon does not also shrink.

Comment: @Aaron, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you want the whole icon and disk smaller? Would you prefer no disk and a black icon? Here are some options: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rumxqunb/3/

Comment: I guess when I said "icon" I was referring to the disc and icon. Your options show how to adjust everything. Thanks again.